# selected-property without without "list" tags CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a set of `<a>` buttons in an `<ul>`. Due to some jQuery-issues I did not use any `<li>` tags around the buttons. Now I would like to use the `.selected` property, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="sidepanel detailkat_tag_cloud">
             <h6 class="sidebar_header">Detailkategorien</h6>
             <div class="detailkatcloud" class="optionset" data-option-key="filter">                        
                 <ul class="optionset" data-option-key="filter">
                   <a href="#filter" data-option-value="*">Alle Anzeigen</a>
                   <a data-option-value=".dk1" href="#filter" title="">dk1</a>
                   <a data-option-value=".dk2" href="#filter" title="">dk2</a>
                   ...
                 </ul>
            </div>
            </div>      
   </div>
```

Now, if I used `<li>` tags the following CSS would work:

```
li.selected a { color: #00ff00; }
```

However, I need to make this work **without** `<li>` tags. I tried all of these:

```
a.selected {}
ul.selected a {}
.detailkat_tag_cloud ul a.selected {}
.detailkatcloud ul a.selected {}
.optionset ul a.selected {} 
ul a.selected {}
```

But none of them work. Please help!

Comment: try to using .selected a{}

Comment: Also, if you're not using `<li>`, might as well ditch the `<ul>` and use a regular div instead. This way is not valid in HTML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS:

```
a.selected { color: #00ff00; }
```

HTML:

```
class="selected"
```

If you haven't added the class to a yet, which according to your code you hadn't.

```
<a href="#filter" data-option-value="*" class="selected">Alle Anzeigen</a>
```

Or if you want to achieve it for hover only.

```
a:hover.selected { color: #00ff00; }
```

Or if you want to achieve it for the current active link.

```
a:active.selected { color: #00ff00; }
```

JSFiddle specific to your problem. It's a workaround because you obviously have to modify different pages. There are ways to avoid doing so but that requires some JS and I'm tired tonight. Here: jsfiddle.net/uwoyvmf7

Comment: Thanks! But now all the '<a>' links look like they're selected, but once you click on one of them, they go back to normal, and the selected one does not look any different...

Comment: Ok I understand what your after, updated answer with the hover method.

THe reason for that happening is that as you assign the class it applies it instantly to all 'a' elements. When you then click one it activates 'a:hover' which is now empty hence removing the class. Therefore you just need to specify that you only want the class to apply to the hover I guess? Added it into the original answer.

Comment: Changing a.selected to a:hover.selected makes it go back to having no effect at all. I need the selected button to be styled differently, so that users can see in which category they're in. Did you mean to add "class='selected'" to every single <a> tag?

Comment: Ok I apologize, I didn't realize you wanted the current selected 'a' link. For that you need '    a:active.selected { color: #00ff00; }'

and once again add the class to the a links.

Comment: I'm sorry, neither adding :hover nor :active change anything. I'm wondering why it can be so difficult when it would be so easy with <li> tags? When I use <li> tags plus the CSS-statement "li.selected a {}" it works beautifully. Not using any "select" classes at all.

Comment: JSFiddle specific to your problem. It's a workaround because you obviously have to modify different pages. There are ways to avoid doing so but that requires some JS and I'm tired tonight. Here: 

http://jsfiddle.net/uwoyvmf7/